# Strange error with Selection object and Userform

Tags: vba, excel

Getting a strange error with this code.  This excerpt is the beginning of the main code.  First it opens a form that takes 3 inputs.  The inputs aren't being used right now so it's not the issue.

```
Public triangle As Range
Public Height, Width, i As Integer


Sub asdf()
Set triangle = Selection
WeightsUserForm.Show
Height = triangle.Rows.Count
Width = triangle.Columns.Count
Debug.Print Height
Debug.Print Width
```

This gives me 12 as Height and 12 as Width, which is correct based on what I've selected.

Now here is the sub that runs when you press OK on the user form:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
Set triangle = Selection
Height = triangle.Rows.Count
Width = triangle.Columns.Count
Debug.Print Height
Debug.Print Width
```

This gives me Height as 28.5 and Width as 99.  I have no clue where this comes from.  I even checked all the objects on my userform as if maybe it was interpreting that as my selection (which is clearly wrong since those objects wouldn't have a rows property).

Ideally I would like to save my initial selection as a "public variable" if that is a real thing.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Further update.  I have set the variable triangle manually now ie

```
triangle = Range("B3","M14")
```

This STILL gives me the same strange dimensions.  Now I'm really stumped.

2xEDIT: When I don't use the variables Height and Width and just refer directly to triangle.Rows.Count and triangle.Columns.Count it gives me correct answers.  So I can run my program properly now.  I would still love to know why using a variable was wrong though.

---

So you're saying that the line

`Public Height,Width,i As Integer`

is only declaring i as an integer and not specifying a type for height and width?  If so that would be my problem.

---

I redid it declaring both Height and Width properly as integers but it still bugged out the same way.  However using private variables W and H defined the same way it works.  *shrug*

Comment: One thing that might help is declaring all your variables.  In the userform code, at least as you've shown it, no variables are declared. In the first routine, you've actually declared `Height` and `Width` as `Variants`. See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx and the section called Pay Attention to Variables Declared with One Dim Statement for an explanation of why they are variants.  Try putting `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules, which will force variable declaration at compile time.

Comment: So, did you try it declaring all your variables as types other than `variant`? I believe that will answer your 2xEdit question.

Comment: One more thought: it's generally suggested to not use Excel reserved words as variable names. `Height` and `Width` are both Excel property names. I'd try changing the variable names to something else, like "TriangleHeight."

Comment: So you're saying that the line

Public Height,Width,i As Integer

is only declaring i as an integer and not specifying a type for height and width?  If so that would be my problem.

Comment: That's what I' saying, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines, I think your issue is that `Debug.Print Height` and `Debug.Print Width` is printing the size of your **form**.

This will happen if your declarations are in a `Module` rather than the `Form` class, because `Height` and `Width` are keywords applicable to the form, so the local versions are used in preference.

To solve, you should do all of these things (not all of this is absolutely necassary, but is all good practice):

- Use `Option Explicit` in *all* your modules
- Don't use Keywords for variable names
- Scope your variables, in order of preference, to `Procedure`, then local `Module`, then public `Module`, and only when there is good reason
- Prefix your remote module calls with the module name, eg `Module1.Height`

BTW, using `Dim Height, Width, i as integer` declares declares `Height` and `Width` as the default type which is `Variant`.